# Make it mandatory to override an @objc method in a base class in a subclass

Tags: swift, oop

At BaseVC I created these methods.

```
// MARK: - NavigationItem
    func addRightBarButtonItem(image: String, style: UIBarButtonItem.Style = .plain) {
        if let image = UIImage(named: image) {
            rightButton = UIBarButtonItem(
                image: image,
                style: style,
                target: self,
                action: #selector(rightBarButtonAction)
            )
            navigationItem.rightBarButtonItem = rightButton
        }
    }

/// This func must be 'overriden' if the subclass will use rightBarButtonItem.
@objc func rightBarButtonAction() {
    fatalError("This method must be overriden")
}
```

I can call it like this in the subclass.

```
addRightBarButtonItem(image: "deleteWhite")

override func rightBarButtonAction() {
        dismiss()
    }
```

How can I make it mandatory to override the following method in the subclass so that it is not forgotten.

```
/// This func must be 'overriden' if the subclass will use rightBarButtonItem.
@objc func rightBarButtonAction() {
    fatalError("This method must be overriden")
}
```

Comment: Why not use a protocol instead of a superclass with an empty implementation and subclasses having to override the empty method? Simply declare a protocol and all conforming types will have to implement the required methods.